# Is there a better way to do  Unobtrusive JavaScript on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The way I found to put javascript on a separated file without the use of RJS or ERB was using an instance variable at javascript_include_tag helper.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag @extra_head_content if !@extra_head_content.nil? %>
```

Then I put the name of the current javascript file at the instance variable from the controller;

```
def index
    @extra_head_content = "test"
#...
end
```

And at my javascript file (test.js) I add some code.

```
 $j(function() {
  alert("test");
 })
```

**Is there any "better" way to do this? Any convention that I'm missing?**

I found a lot of information for UJS to XHR(AJAX) but nothing abot the conventions for a simple thing like " unobtrusive (document).ready"

I'm using rails 3-0-9.

Comment: you probably mean unobtrusive

Comment: A side note: `if !@extra_head_content.nil?` can be replaced by `unless @extra_head_content.present?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do something like this:

in ApplicationHelper:

```
def javascript(file)
  content_for(:javascript_at_head){ javascript_include_tag file }
end
```

in layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= yield(:javascript_at_head) %>
```

and in another template:

```
<% javascript :test %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`content_for` and `yield`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for)?